# check if directory exists on remote machine before sftp

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

this my function that copies file from local machine to remote machine with paramiko, but it doesn't check if the destination directory exists and continues copying and doesn't throws error if remote path doesn't exists

```
def copyToServer(hostname, username, password, destPath, localPath):
    transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    sftp.put(localPath, destPath)
    sftp.close()
    transport.close()
```

i want to check if path on remote machine exists and throw error if not.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do

```py
def copyToServer(hostname, username, password, destPath, localPath):
    transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))

    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    try:
        sftp.put(localPath, destPath)
        sftp.close()
        transport.close() 
        print(" %s    SUCCESS    " % hostname )
        return True

    except Exception as e:
        try:
            filestat=sftp.stat(destPath)
            destPathExists = True
        except Exception as e:
            destPathExists = False

        if destPathExists == False:
        print(" %s    FAILED    -    copying failed because directory on remote machine doesn't exist" % hostname)
        log.write("%s    FAILED    -    copying failed    directory at remote machine doesn't exist\r\n" % hostname)
        else:
        print(" %s    FAILED    -    copying failed" % hostname)
        log.write("%s    FAILED    -    copying failed\r\n" % hostname)
        return False
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion it's better to avoid exceptions, so unless you have lots of folders, this is a good option for you:

```
if folder_name not in self.sftp.listdir(path):
    sftp.mkdir(os.path.join(path, folder_name))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `chdir()` method of [`SFTPClient`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.chdir). It checks if the remote path exists, raises error if not.

```
try:
    sftp.chdir(destPath)
except IOError as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: I would replace `chdir()` with `stat()` just to avoid any issues if we set the wrong working directory with the `chdir()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the listdir method within SFTPClient. You will probably have to use this recursively to ensure the entire path is valid.